# Getting values of an array XSLT

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt

please help,

I have this values:

```
<xsl:variable name="PB" select="'/join/id/stop/regelingtype_007'"/>
<xsl:variable name="I" select="'/join/id/stop/regelingtype_008'"/> 
<xsl:variable name="VR" select="'/join/id/stop/regelingtype_009'"/>
<xsl:variable name="P" select="'/join/id/stop/regelingtype_010'"/>
```

I have this array

```
<xsl:variable name="OP-implementatie" select="[
        $PB,
        $I,
        $VR,
        $P
        ]"/>
```

Now I want to analyze this xslt with another xslt
I get a reference to the array like this

```
<xsl:variable name="vars" select="document('xxx')s/*/xsl:variable" />
```

I find the array like this

```
<xsl:variable name="array" select="$vars[@name = 'OP-implementatie']/@select"/>
```

Till here it works fine, I can it refers to the right array But now I want to use the values:

```
<xsl:element name="var"><xsl:value-of select="$array"/></xsl:element>
```

It just prints the array like this

```
<var>[         $PB,         $I,         $VR,         $P         ]</var>
```

And when I do this:

```
<xsl:element name="var"><xsl:value-of select="$array[1]"/></xsl:element>
```

It does exactly the same.
I was hoping to retrieve the values of the array one by one, how can I do that?

Thanks very much for any help

Best regards
Bert Verhees

Comment: What is the result you are trying to get? And which verion of XSLT can you use?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to import the document with e.g. `<xsl:import href="sheet1.xsl"/>`, then you can select `$OP-implementatie` as the complete array and use e.g. `$OP-implementatie?1` or `$OP-implementatie(1)` to get the first item in the array. It is not clear why you need to use the other XSLT as ordinary XML parsed with `doc` or `document`.

Comment: It is a promising solution, thanks. The disadvantage is the import is a problem because of conflicting root element. Or is it possible to import nodes from another document? Why I need to do that is a long story, it has to with analyzing xslt documents.

Comment: @BertVerhees, any imported should normally have lower priority than your importing code so conflicts should not arise.

Comment: I will try tomorrow and will let you know. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, it does not work, internal references of the stylesheet imported start to object, because in the importing situation their XPath has changed.

Comment: For others who are searching the answer for a similar problem, I solved like this:

<xsl:variable name="AMvB_MR_BRG" select="/regelingtype_001 /regelingtype_002"/>

The strings without quotes per item and forwarding slash, and that worked.